# Random numbers with interval prompt and fix

Tags: javascript, random, prompt

I try to fill an array with random numbers:

```
var randomArray = new Array(10);
function randFillArray(array, aInx, zInx) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = randomFromInterval(aInx, zInx);
    }
}
function randomFromInterval(from, to){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() *(to - from + 1)) + from);
}
var minV = 1;
var maxV = 6;
randFillArray(randomArray, minV, maxV);
for(var i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
        document.write(randomArray[i]+"<br />");
    }
```

this is work good.
But if i want to input min and max value like this:

```
var minV = prompt("min");
var maxV = prompt("max");
```

with same min = 1 and max = 6, i can get 0 in array. Some one know why?

Answer (score 2):

Values entered in prompt window are stored as strings, so you have to evaluate them for integers. There are at least 2 ways of doing that.

1. Using function `parseInt`:

   ```
   var minV = parseInt(prompt("min"));
   var maxV = parseInt(prompt("max"));
   ```
2. Multiplying the 'string' by 1:

   ```
   var minV = prompt("min");
   var maxV = prompt("max");
   minV *= 1;
   maxV *= 1;
   ```

Comment: Feel like sharing at least one of the 2 ways?

Comment: Thanx. I did it in this way: var minV = parseInt(prompt("min"));  var maxV = parseInt(prompt("max")); and it work good now!

Answer (score 1):

```
var minV = parseInt(prompt("min"));
var maxV = parseInt(prompt("max"));
```